# switch from one to another layout using radioButton

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, radio-group

hi i am trying to get through my xml files using a radio group which in a same activity but it perfom just for the first click here is my xml file

```
  package com.example.carteacache;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.RadioButton;
  import android.widget.RadioGroup;
  import android.widget.Spinner;
  import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  public Button bouton1;
  public Button bouton2;
  private Spinner spinner;
  private RadioGroup radiobutO;
  private RadioButton chRadio;
  private String [] paysListe  = {"Sénégal","Gambie","Sierra Leone","Burkina","Mali"};
@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bouton1  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bouton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    radiobutO =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    populateSpinner();
```

Here is where i am navigating thought the option which will allow  user to get from one to another xml file

```
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
        {
            chRadio  =(RadioButton)rg.findViewById(radiobutO.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            checkedId =  group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            switch(checkedId)
            {

            case R.id.radio1:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, chRadio.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                break;
            case R.id.radio2:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, chRadio.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
                // TODO Something
                break;
            case R.id.radio3:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, chRadio.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
                // TODO Something

                break;
            }
        }
    });


      bouton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

   }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

 private void populateSpinner() {


        //txtCategory.setText("");

        List<String> pays = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < paysListe.length; i++) {
            pays.add(paysListe[i]);
        }

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pays);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        spinnerAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    }
       }
```

Am using radioButton to get to next xlm file.
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: add this code  radiobutO =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);  again after changing content view to assign the radiobutton again

Comment: Thanx Hamzah Malick i try it and i will tell you

Comment: it still doing the same the first work and change the current xml file but not the rest